# Inclined plane vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors

I have a question,

I need to find $P$ in the following situation. A box of mass 5kg is in equilibrium on a slope at $pi/6$ from the horizontal. I need to find the magnitude of the force in the positive x-direction. Could someoene please explain why I am getting the wrong answer and how to actually find the value of $P$?

I am assuming that $P$ is a component of the force down the slope. The magnitude of the force down the slope is $F=5g*sin(pi/6)$. So, I made a force triangle (as can be seen in the diagram), where the hypotenuse is the force down the slope, and is resolved into $Fg=mg$ and $P$ which is the horizontal force. Having done so, I tried to solve for $P$ by:

$P=5g*tan(pi/6)$

This gives me the answer $5g\sqrt3$ but the answer is $5g/\sqrt3$

Because I am assuming $P$ is a component of $5g*sin(pi/6)$, I also tried doing:

P=5g*sin(pi/6)*cos(pi/6)$

but this gave me $(5g\sqrt3)/4$

Why are these approaches not working? Thanks!

p.s uploading an image seemed like the best means of illustrating my question

[image]

Comment: Aren't you simply missing some forces on this force diagram? There will also be a normal force, which should have some influence

Comment: I am just trying to understand why my current approach isn't working, but yes, the diagram does not contain all the vectors/resolutes acting on the object

Comment: Would you mind writing out the procedure, especially the force balance that you have set up? I think your approach is ok (although it is hard to see clearly from the image - it would be easier to have i written out), but you might use a wrong force balance equation. Would you mind adding to your question the full procedure written in text and mathJax?

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks for the update. I need to ask a few more questions, though, because it still isn't clear to me. Firstly, the box is stated to be in equilibrium. So there must be some force pulling upwards along the incline - would that be friction maybe? And now, what exactly are we looking for? The x-component of this friction force?

Comment: It is a smooth surface sorry, I should have provided that. And we are assuming that the force P is causing that equilibrium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal force is missing. It cannot be left out, because it is actually the normal force which balances out the horizontal pulling force $P$.

When the angled normal force $n$, the vertical weight $w$ and the horizontal $P$ are all included, we can set up a force balance equation (Newton's 1st law) in the y and x directions:

$$\sum F_y=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n_y-w=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n_y-mg=0\\
\sum F_x=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad P-n_x=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad P=n_x$$

Now we see that $P$ is balanced out by the normal force's x component and has got nothing to do with the weight (because they are perpendicular). The normal force does depend on the weight, though, since its y component balances out the weight.

The next step now is to use some cosine and sine magic with the angle of the normal force, to find the proper expression for the normal force x and y components to plug in. This should do it.

My recommendation is that you redraw the force diagram to include all forces and then look at the normal force triangle and figure out (in the same way as you've done above for the other triangle) how to express $n_x$ and $n_y$ with a fitting sine or cosine relation.

Comment: You were right, including the normal force enabled me to create a correct force equilibrium. Cheers